# How can I request that a question merge be reversed?

Tags: support, questions, moderation, merged-questions

It's extremely convenient for when you check out a git repo and forgot to specify the recursive flag to google "git forgot recurse" or any number of searches like that which all lead to this thread: [Git - forgot to use --recursive while cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795901/git-forgot-to-use-recursive-while-cloning)

Which used to contain a single very highly upvoted answer. But, the thread was erroneously closed and merged with a thread about how to check out recursively, which is a *very* different question. I can't find any way to contest this closure, or contact the user who closed it.

EDIT: Clarification, since it is not immediately clear. The original post says what to do if you checked out a module which you did not realize had submodules and you need those checked out. There is a single one-line answer for how to solve it because you "forgot" to check out submodules. The merged thread is ideally how you would check out a repository if you wanted to also checkout submodules. You would find this thread if you've already done a checkout but now need to fetch the submodules.

Is there any recourse when a highly ranked mod does something in error like this?

Comment: Well, you've found the recourse, post about it on meta. Your question might benefit from explaining how it's different instead of just stating that it is, since it was at least similar enough to this moderator to merge it.

Comment: I don't understand that merge either. It looks like two answers were merged, but both also got deleted by the mod on the other question, so what was the point in merging them?

Comment: @ErikA So the idea would be to post here about the difference?  I mean the general idea is that one is how do you do this thing?  And the other is "If I've already done the wrong thing how do I fix it?"  

Because of the weird combination of actions tom pointed out, I really think this was actually a mistake. I just can't find any way to request a review of the action.

Comment: The best way to do it is post here, with a link to the question as you've done. What you're missing is an explanation as to why the merge wasn't optimal, or perhaps even erroneous (It might not be immediately obvious to folks).

Comment: I have edited the original post to clarify.

Comment: As far as I understood it, merging is not undo-able. Has that changed?

Comment: @TylerH It is possible to unmerge questions, but this can only be done by employees: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333997/

Comment: @TylerH Mods can't undo it via our tooling, no. I suspect a dev could undo it, but I have no idea how hard it is, assuming they would do it.

Comment: As someone that doesn't know git....how does it _not_ answer the question, is that not covered by what the `git submodule init/update` answers say?

Comment: @Nick those were probably merged in though

Comment: @Zoe no, it's in 3 of the 4 top voted answers (also looking at post timelines none of the answers merged in are still undeleted, as Tom said)

Comment: This is what happens when question duplicates are interpreted as "you can find your answer over here," even if the questions themselves are completely different.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, it isn't, since the moderator closed the question as a duplicate immediately before merging it, which means that he decided the questions should be merged independently of any definition of "duplicate".

Comment: @pppery: I don't presume to know what goes on in the mind of a moderator, since I'm not actually a mind reader.  But since the two questions are clearly *not the same question*, you can draw your own conclusions from that.

Comment: In all honesty, this wouldn't be an issue if the thread that was closed didn't have the exact answer to the question that was being posed *and* also be the top google result for the issue at hand... But `git clone --recursive` and `git submodule update --init --recursive` have very different applications.

Answer (score 2):

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795901/git-forgot-to-use-recursive-while-cloning)'s most upvoted answer was [this one by rmunn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33795927). It said:

> [How to "git clone" including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796927/2314532) has an answer to this
> question. Just do:
>
> ```
> cd my-just-cloned-repo
> git submodule update --init --recursive
> ```
>
> and that should fetch your submodules for you.

Note that it is little more than a link to and a copy-paste of the most upvoted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules). It was primarily on this basis that I performed the merge. When two questions have identical answers, they're a good candidate for a merge.

---

There was [another answer to the question, by Javier C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074504). It said:

> You can check this post:
>
> [How to git clone including submodules if you have already cloned the
> project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774204/3739382)
>
> In resume:
>
> 1. Go to your project folder:
>
>    ```
>    cd path/to/your/projectFolder
>    ```
> 2. Init submodules in the project:
>
>    ```
>    git submodule init
>    ```
> 3. Update submodules in the project:
>
>    ```
>    git submodule update
>    ```

Once again, this is little more than a "stub" answer linking to [Javier C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774204) on [the main question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules).

---

Using [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200806164203/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules), I did a side-by-side comparison and confirmed that there were *no other answers* to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795901/git-forgot-to-use-recursive-while-cloning). **Its only two answers were little more than "stubs" linking to answers on the main question.** And these were not just obscure answers in the "long tail" of answers, but highly-upvoted answers in both directions. There was clear and compelling evidence that myriad users found the answers to be helpful in solving their problem, suggesting clearly that the questions were duplicates by Stack Overflow's definition. Furthermore, they were duplicates in my judgment, a judgment that was specifically informed by seeking solutions to the exact same problem myself, giving me a unique opportunity to actually test the proposed solutions and confirm that the two questions had exactly the same answer.

As such, I think the merge was completely appropriate and correct. The second question was an exact duplicate of the first, having exactly the same answers.

Since the two answers that I quoted above were mere "stubs", redirecting to answers that *already existed on the same page*, I deleted them after merging the questions.

Comment: The difference is one is before you check things out, i.e. the answer to the question that this was merged with; and the other is after you have checked out a repository.

Before (answer to merged thread) `git clone --recursive [repo]`

After (answer to thread that was closed): `git submodule update --init --recursive`

You have to fish through the answers section to find the second, which should be in a different thread, as this was the top google result for the issue.  It makes the solution take much longer to find as you have to fish around in the second thread.

Comment: @Charles You don't have to do any fishing. The top answer to the duplicate question was simply quoting the top answer to the main question. All you have to do is read it... "For already cloned repos...use:".

Comment: The top answer does not have it. It's down in the comments (not even top comment!) for the top answer.

Comment: I just realized, I had it sorted by activity instead of votes.  Indeed, that is decent as long as the sort is set correctly.